# Magento search does not recognize one word: "bow"

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, search, catalogsearch, search-terms

We have a line of "bow" products, but the Magento search just completely ignores this word. It works just fine with all other products. If I search just the word "bow" it return no results. If I search the word "bow" with another term, it just ignore the word "bow" and search for the other term. e.g. if I search "red bow" it will only search for the word "red."

The minimal query length is set to 1. The name and description attributes are searchable. The products are searchable. They're in a "bow" category, which is not at root level. I've checked every setting I can think of or seen reccommended. There are no 3rd party modules that should be touching the search. Again, the search works fine otherwise. The bow products do come up in the search for other terms. It's literally just the word "bow" that it's ignoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've set the name and description attributes to be searchable - that's usually what is preventing a site from displaying search results like this.

So, the first thing I'd recommend is a full reindex of the site.  That might clear the issue up.  (It's kind of the IT guy telling you to reboot your computer.)

Second, I'd recommend creating a custom search rule for the word bow that redirects to a Bow Category page.

Here's a quick screenshot of how to do this in a Magento 1.9 site:

[image: Setting up a custom search rule]

Let me know if this works...

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried reindexing several times and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I did create the search redirect like you suggested and that's working. I'm still baffled as to what it has against this specific word, but everyone is satisfied with this fix so thank you!